# Twitter API no longer returning results

Tags: twitter

Has something with the twitter API changed?  This link was returning results earlier today but for whatever reason it seems to have stopped?

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=vine&callback=?

Also, clicking on the links in the examples no longer work?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. You've found out how **the version 1 api has been deprecated** / is in the process of being removed.

From now on, all your requests to the twitter API will be **required to have authentication** (OAuth), and for some this was a nightmare to figure out.

Fortunately, I wrote a [lengthy post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) (with pictures) explaining how to set yourself up a twitter dev account / application, get a set of keys, and then I created a [library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) to perform authenticated requests for you.

The only downside is that this library is written in [php](/questions/tagged/php), and from looking at your profile you use ASP.net - so try googling for a library for your specific language if you don't want to use PHP.

In any case, **no more unauthenticated requests for you** ;) You need to dig in with OAuth now!

Comment: it was working earlier.  Also the V1 API isn't set to deprecate until 6/11/13.  Also, I'm doing all of this in javascript currently.  Haven't used any server side code yet.

Comment: @KyleRogers So knowing it'll cease to function in 5 days, don't ya think it's best to use something that'll last more than a week? :P

Comment: 100% yes, but it still isn't making me happy

Comment: I know, it's a nightmare. For asp.net MVC, try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515969/net-twitter-oauth-how-to-perform-a-successful-get-request), or google "ASP.net mvc twitter 1.1 api". Hopefully you'll find something specific to your language.

Comment: Also, there's a [bug right now](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1072) that may be the issue. Regardless, I suggest migrating to 1.1 ASAP :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding in ASP.NET, I recommend the Twitterizer library.  It's written and maintained by a fellow who helped me get my own Twitter .NET library off the ground when I was doing that sort of thing.