# Twitter API Getting recent tweets by screen name

Tags: twitter

I am using the below api url for getting the most recent tweets by screen name of user. But is not pulling recent ones. Is there any url for pulling the same?

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=virendersehwag&count=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **version 1.0** API that has been deprecated and will **not work at all any more in four days**.

[image]

For more information on the above, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957749/twitter-search-api-php/16960422#16960422), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953102/twitter-api-mistake/16957633#16957633) and finally / most importantly **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)** on how you need to make authenticated requests to twitter in the future.

For **statuses**, you will need to be using the **[GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)** method from the twitter 1.1 API. Again, without authentication, version 1 (it has /1/ in the url) API requests will *completely stop working* in 4 days time.

You can read more about the 1.1 API in [the 1.1 API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

Comment: @SSS Glad I could help. I see from your profile that you use C#, so I suggest [this post](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16281) for your language - there should be plenty of info on google :)