# Twitter: Hash tag json api

Tags: twitter

In my app, I am just displaying tweets of a public profile page using twitter json api.

eg. **`"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=abc"`.**

Earlier it was working properly but recently not getting any response from the server. I have seen couple of posts on stackoverflow itself stating that twitter json server keeps getting down in few days. so, is there any other way to get json reponse for a particular hashtag.

Thanks.

Comment: EXACT of [Twitter API no longer returning results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953102/twitter-api-no-longer-returning-results) - do your research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing that request, Twitter explains that

> The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

You need to use the new API (v1.1) which requires user authentication for every request, and, unfortunately, is more complicated in querying simple things like search results.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried new search json api. eg."https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23abc", but got error as "Bad Authentication data". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @IOSDev All requests now require OAuth authentication. Since it's in an app, you can use the Apple-provided APIs for communicating with the Twitter API without a problem. Post a new question here if necessary.